# how to pass environment variables to hyperledger chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is it possible to inject environment variables into chaincode at launch time so that they can be accessed when transactions are invoked? Does the chaincode container inherit the environment from the peer container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ... you cannot pass environment variables into chaincode and no it does not inherent any specific environment variables the peer process has access to.

If you want to pass runtime parameters into a chaincode instance at startup you should pass them as parameters to the Init() function and then save them as chaincode state.   You can then pull them / use them in your chaincode.